# Como manter o elemento na posição final da animação?

Tags: css, css3, animação

Estou utilizando esse código para fazer um efeito e manter o elemento na posição final da animação, ou seja, à direita.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="anim">


</div>
```

**Código CSS**:

```
#anim{

  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

}

#anim:hover{

  -webkit-animation-name: toRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;

}



@-webkit-keyframes toRight{

  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 200px;}
}

@keyframes toRight{

  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 200px;}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [**`animation-fill-mode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) com **`forwards`**.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes right {
  from { left: 0px   }
  to   { left: 200px }
}

@keyframes right {
  from { left: 0px   }
  to   { left: 200px }
}


div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width:  100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  
  -webkit-animation: right 2s forwards;
          animation: right 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Muito bom @re22. Mas eu tentei fazer com uma animação que aumentava o tamanho de um **input**, coloquei no mesmo formato **right 2s forwards** mas não funcionou. Será que pra elementos input é algo diferente?

Comment: Consegui, é que no **código** do exemplo você não colocou o **animation-fill-mode: forwards;**

Comment: Eu sei @re22, eu troquei os nomes, mas na mesma sequência que você fez **animation: toRight 2s forwards;** não funcionou rsrs.

Comment: Se estiver no Chrome, é preciso usar *vendor prefix*: `-webkit-animation: toRight 2s forwards;`

Comment: Agora sim, funcionou dessa forma aí.

Answer (score 3):

Experimenta adicionar `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, por exemplo:

```
-webkit-animation: toRight 1.0s forwards;
```